# Row/Column coloring for TableLayoutPanel (vs2008, winform)

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008

Can i add particular color for entire Row or Column in TableLayoutPanel ?
How ? please provide sample code if any ..

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes you can.

Use the TableLayoutPanel's CellPaint event to test for which row/column has called the event and then use a Graphic object size to the rectangle to set the cell's color.

Like this (for the first and third rows):

```
     private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.CellPaint += new TableLayoutCellPaintEventHandler(tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint);
     }


    void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == 0 || e.Row == 2) {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, r);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to make sure you dispose the brush. Wrap its creation in a using(){} statement or use the static Brushes.Blue. Otherwise you leak memory on every paint.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, Eilon - and mentioning to option to use the static Brushes.

Comment: `Brushes.Blue` is a static property, so I wouldn't dispose it, otherwise it might become invalid next time you use it.

Answer (score 5):

**I found this answer much easier to implement:**

This allowed me to put a full backcolor on my cell.

1. Create a `Panel`, which has a backcolor, and
2. I `Dock` that `Panel` in my `TableLayoutPanel`

Then that `TableLayoutPanel` Cell has a
    backcolor.

My Code ended up looking like this:

```
Panel backgroundColorPanel = new Panel();
backgroundColorPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 243, 243);
backgroundColorPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
backgroundColorPanel.Margin = new Padding(0);
backgroundColorPanel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left));
backgroundColorPanel.AutoSize = true;
backgroundColorPanel.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
this.originalTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(backgroundColorPanel, 0, row);
```

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=444944

Comment: This works but is not very efficient in terms of lines of code required, memory usage, or processor cycles.