# Yearly Calendar Winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar

I am looking for a way to develop this :
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/193313Capture.jpg

As you can see, I am gonna need to add event (drawing rectangles) into that calendar.
Althought my countless hours of research, I couldn't find anything close to what I want so I am gonna make it from scratch.

Any idea on how I can manage to do it? Should I use a datagridview ?

Comment: Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Comment: @AndrewBarber good luck in the moderator election! reading this helpful response makes me feel that I upvoted your nomination correctly.

Comment: if you want to draw a lot, like the arrows, a lot of lines, you might try WPF instead of Winforms. if you only have to display that calendar and not edit it, I would probably use the drawing library only and no datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is using [TableLayoutPanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). Specially look at the methods [SetColumnSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcolumnspan.aspx) and [SetRowSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setrowspan.aspx)

The code for painting different cells borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032381/row-column-coloring-for-tablelayoutpanel-vs2008-winform)

```
 private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.CellPaint += new TableLayoutCellPaintEventHandler(tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint);
 }


void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row == 0 || e.Row == 2) {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: That calendar will be in read only mode. I have not thought of the drawing library, thought it would be too much of a pain to develop. Could be fun actually.
I will look into TableLayoutPanel Class as well, seems like I out for a long day.

Comment: @user2071260 so tablelayoutpanel is just perfect, see the edit

Comment: I understand the logic. Thank you sir !!