# tablelayoutpanel not raising cellpaint event

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

I am trying to paint the rows of my tablelayoutpanel object. I added a handler for the cellpaint event but I can't even get the debugger to catch this event. Is there something else that I need to configure on the tablelayoutpanel so that I can custom paint my cells?

I have tried a forced call to invalidate on usercontrol load but that didn't help.

Here's my code:

```
 Private Sub TableLayoutPanel3_CellPaint(sender As Object, e As TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel3.CellPaint
    Select Case e.Row
        Case 1
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, e.CellBounds)
        Case 2
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.CellBounds)
        Case 3
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.CellBounds)
    End Select
End Sub
```

I used [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032381/row-column-coloring-for-tablelayoutpanel-vs2008-winform) as a reference.

Edit: The objects within my tablelayoutpanel cells were not set to autosize. When I enabled autosize I found the cellpaint event would raise and my object visually displayed as I had expected. I suppose this behavior is by design.

[image: Autosize cell object true vs false blocks cellpaint event]

Comment: The CellPaint event only occurs when the cell is redrawn. Are you sure you are redrawing it?

Comment: It should draw the cells on load even though i built my panel at designtime, right?

Comment: In the reference that you showed, the answer in the question seems to create a `New TableLayoutCellPaintEventHandler(tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint)` ... Creating the event to be triggered. Try that :)

Comment: By the way, I have tested out your code and it worked for me. Try rebuilding / cleaning the solution and test again. It should work.

Comment: In converting the example code from the reference link I still can't get the event to trigger. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I suggest you startup a new project completely and just try to make that work. That's what I did and it worked fine. If not, paste your code of your Form1.vb

Comment: Hi Alex, So the code does work in a form object but i am hosting this tablelayoutpanel inside of a usercontrol which is loaded at runtime. Any suggestions? You should submit an answer so I can give you points for your help on this btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to load the UserControl on runtime, I will create a button to trigger this. I could do it on Form_Load but for this example, I'll make it on the Button_Click.

I have the following files:

- Form1.vb
- UserControl1.vb

---

### Form1.vb

In my `Form1.vb` I have a TableLayoutPanel (used for resizing the controls). In the first row of my TableLayoutPanel I have a button which notifies the user to "Load User Control". The second row is a place holder for my UserControl.

[image: Form1.vb]

The following code simply adds in the UserControl1 that I created into my TableLayoutPanel

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ucColors As New UserControl1 'Create a new instance of the UserControl
        ucColors.Dock = DockStyle.Fill 'Make it dock to it's parent container (this tablelayoutpanel)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ucColors, 0, 1) 'Add the control to the tablelayoutpanel
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

### UserControl1.vb

This is my UserControl1.vb. I created a TableLayoutPanel in this UserControl and docked it (fill). This makes the TableLayoutPanel resize to the size of the UserControl. I created three rows because you had three rows in your example.

[image: UserControl1.vb]

This is the only code I need to paint the UserControl>TableLayoutPanels>Rows.

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(sender As Object, e As TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.CellPaint
        Select Case e.Row
            Case 0 'Row 1
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, e.CellBounds)
            Case 1 'Row 2
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.CellBounds)
            Case 2 'Row 3
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.CellBounds)
            End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

### RunTime

When I execute my program, the Form1 pops up:

[image: Form1_BeforeClick]

And then when I press the Load button, this occurs:

[image: Form1_AfterClick]

---

So, when I clicked on my button, a new instance of the user control was created which made it execute the Cell_Paint in the UserControl.

Hopefully this clears things up!

Comment: It turns out that my issue had to do with the configuration of my tablelayoutpanel object. When I dropped a new one on the usercontrol at designtime and added the handler to the existing cellpaint event I found it to work as expected. So, i'm going to delete my other one and fill the rows with my label objects at runtime instead of doing it all at designtime. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @TWood Glad you figured it out! :)

Comment: The culprit property appears to be an object with property autosize set to false on any of the cells. I added a pic to original post to reflect this.